# Authentication failure in IIS following unc connection change

Tags: iis, authorization

I have my localhost site set up in IIS 10, connecting as a local user (under the "Connect as ..." option in Basic Settings.  This was working fine, until I needed to change the password for the local user.  Now I get a 401.2 authentication error when browsing to my site, and cannot figure out why.

I reset the password used in the "Connect as..." option, and "Test Settings..." works.

Also, I rebooted my machine following the password change.

Any idea why I am now getting the 401.2 error and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  I also had to change the saved password going through the Anonymous Authentication settings.